# Regex matches a text with begin and end arguments

Tags: regex

i need help for regex.

I have a string :

> 1°) Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem Ipsum has  been the industry's standard dummy text
> ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
> and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting  :
>
> 2°)Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
> industry. Lorem  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
> ever since the 1500s, when  an unknown printer took a galley of type
> and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

Of this string i want 2 matches `1°) string following` and `2°) string following`

I tried with `(?<\d°\)).*` but this regex does not match the enter key.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try `(?m)^\d+°\).*(?:\n(?!\d+°).*)*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0kstS/1))

Comment: Please mention language/tool, split is more simple: [`\n(?=\d°\))`](https://regex101.com/r/Bi5Goi/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^\d+°\).*(?:\n(?!\d+°\)).*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0kstS/3). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - a MULTILINE option
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `°\)` - a `°)` fixed string
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n(?!\d+°\)).*)*` - zero or more lines that are not starting with one or more digits and `°)`

A splitting approach would involve a pattern like

```
(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=\d+°\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0kstS/4). *Details*:

- `(?:\r\n?|\n)` - a line break sequence
- `(?=\d+°\))` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more digits and then `°)` immediately to the right of the current location.